# Removing stopwords from a string without extra/unnecessary looping

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I'm trying to clean up my string and remove particular words. I have a working piece of code but it's not pretty and not robust.

**input**: the_for_an_apple_this

**remove words**: the, for, an

**output**: apple_this

```
#!/bin/bash
str="the_for_an_apple_this"
echo $str

# looping is down because after the awk gsup the next match wouldn't work 
counter=0
while [ $counter -le 10 ] 
do
    # replace with , "_" ?? is this correct, it seems to work
    str=`echo $str | awk '{gsub(/(^|_)(the|for|an)($|_)/,"_")}1'`
    ((counter++))
    echo $str
done

# remove beginning or trailing _
str=`echo $str | awk '{gsub(/(^)_/,"")}1' | awk '{gsub(/_($)/,"")}1'`
echo $str
```

1. Is this a good way of doing this? (I'm using awk because I need best cross platform compatibility and sed was giving issues)
2. How can I replace my while condition so that it stops when no more matches occur.

**testable version here**: http://rextester.com/BHYSP47270

How can I clean this up and make it work without a fragile counter?

Comment: Note too that it's much better to have just one `awk` script processing your whole input, rather than a separate copy of `awk` handling each line. `awk` is faster than bash is, but if you keep starting it up, running one line through it and shutting it down over and over, you don't get any benefit of that performance delta -- and indeed, you get something many times *slower* than native bash string manipulation would be.

Comment: Speaking to your real use case, though -- do you need to retain ordering? Generally, set arithmetic is a job for `comm`; see [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only native bash logic:

```
#!/bin/bash
remove_stopwords() {
  local old_settings=$-  # store original shell settings so we can undo set -f
  local -a words=( )     # create "words" array as a local variable
  local IFS=_            # set the underscore to be the only character than separates words
  set -f                 # disable globbing to make unquoted expansion safe

  for word in $1; do     # split str on chars in IFS (underscores) and iterate
    case $word in "the"|"for"|"an") continue;; esac  # skip stopwords
    words+=( "$word" )   # put words we didn't skip into our array
  done
  echo "${words[*]}"     # join words with underscores (first IFS character) and echo

  if ! [[ $old_settings = *f* ]]; then set +f; fi # undo "set -f"
}

str="the_for_an_apple_this"
remove_stopwords "$str"
```

You can see this running at https://ideone.com/hrd1vA

---

Or, more terse: run the function body in a subshell. Also edited to use more bash-only features

```
remove_stopwords() (     # parentheses launch a subshell
    words=( )
    IFS=_
    set -f               # disable globbing
    for word in $1; do   # unquoted for word splitting
        [[ $word == @(the|for|an) ]] || words+=( "$word" )
    done
    echo "${words[*]}"
)
```

Comment: Nice. I was getting complicated with an associative array to hold the words to remove.

Comment: I wrote an associative-array version first, and decided I didn't want to deal with the bash 4.0 requirement and went back and did this before posting.

Comment: thanks!!! how do I undo the set -f setting and how do I undo the IFS setting? I want to make sure when my method returns to not affect the rest of the running script

Comment: `set +f` undoes `set -f`. The easiest thing to do with the IFS change is to just scope it to a subshell: Put a `(` in your code before you change IFS globally, and a `)` after you're done needing that value. Also an option to change it as a function-local variable; I can edit to show that.

Comment: @Newton, ...see edits that change IFS and `set -f` only within a function.

Comment: super great idea! thanks again

Comment: If you define the function with parentheses, it will run in a subshell so you don't have to localize IFS or remember the shell settings: `remove_stopwords() ( ... )`

Comment: Yup -- that's a terseness-vs-performance tradeoff to decide which route to go.

Comment: glenn amazing thank you! I did not know that

Answer (score 3):

What about using awk alone?

```
$ tail file1 file2
==> file1 <==
an_for_the

==> file2 <==
the_for_an_apple_this
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="_"} NR==FNR{r[$1];next} ($1 in r){next} 1' file1 file2
apple_this
```

This reads through your "exclusion" string (stored in `file1`), storing words that are separated by underscores as indices in an array. It then steps through your input string (stored in `file2`), with the same record separator, skipping records that are members of the array that was created in the previous step.

May require some fine tuning with respect to the end of line.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply with bash as:

```
shopt -s extglob
str="the_for_an_apple_this"
for words in "the" "for" "an"; do
   str=${str//$words/}
done
str=${str//+(_)/_}; str=${str#_}; str=${str%_}
```

The loop can be removed if you use:

```
shopt -s extglob
str="the_for_an_apple_this"
str=${str//@(the|for|an)/}
str=${str//+(_)/_}; str=${str#_}; str=${str%_}
```

In this solution we make use of the extended glob options stemming from KSH:

Comment: that's great thank you! how do I undo the shopt -s setting? I want to make sure when my method returns to not affect the rest of the running script

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` sets the option and `shopt -u extglob` unsets it.

Comment: `str="the_for_plan_apple_this"` = oops.

Comment: @PesaThe I could argue that the OP did not specify that the word he wants to remove should be preceded and followed by underscores. But then again, you are completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, a perl version:

```
perl -lne '
    %remove = map {$_=>1} qw(the for an);
    print join "_", grep {$_ and not $remove{$_}} split /_/;
' <<< "the_for_an_apple__the_this_for"
```

```
apple_this
```

Or a case insensitive version

```
perl -lne '
    %remove = map {uc,1} qw(the for an);
    print join "_", grep {$_ and not $remove{+uc}} split /_/;
' <<< "tHe_For_aN_aPple__thE_This_fOr"
```

```
aPple_This
```